# Get timezone shortcut based on UTC offset in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

I want to get the timezone shortcut like EST (for eastern standard), PST (pacific), and so on based on the UTC offset. I realize it's not a simple problem and there can be more than one location based on a particular offset, but that's okay.

I'm trying to get it using Util Calendar object but I don't seem to get a string but rather just the offset.

```
public String foo(int offset)
{
....
return TimeZoneShortcut;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by user2580516](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21791381/642706) is correct. I can add a bit more.

## Avoid Three-Letter Codes

The three-letter time zone IDs are neither standardized nor unique. Avoid them.

For example, `IST` is used to mean `India Standard Time` *or* `Irish Standard Time`. There are many such collisions.

## Time Zone Names

Instead of 3-letter codes, use proper time zone names. Examples: "Europe/Paris", "America/Montreal", and "Asia/Kolkata".

There does not seem to be an official standard for time zone names. That surprises me; hopefully I'm wrong and someone can fill me in. At any rate, a commonly used list is take from the [*tz database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (formerly known as the *Olson database*), as [listed in this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The excellent date-time library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), has a method to generate a list of its [currently known time zone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

The time zone names change over time, some are added, and their rules change too. All that is determined by politicians and bureaucrats, so changes are last-minute and not always sensible. So you should take care to keep your date-time library up-to-date, or at least update its contained time zone database.

## Impossible Question – Cannot Determine Time Zone

A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is more than just an numerical offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. A time zone also contains the set of rules for [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST) and other anomalies.

So you cannot infer a time zone from an offset. You can *guess*, but you cannot be sure.

For example, take the offset of `+01:00`. Is that "Europe/Paris" or "Africa/Lagos"? Both have an offset of one hour ahead of UTC. So does it matter which you use? Yes… France observes Daylight Saving Time but Nigeria does not. Assigning the wrong time zone means your date-time calculations will be wrong.

Another twist… Perhaps that `+01:00` was recorded in London during the summer time. In summer, London observes DST and moves its clocks 1 hour ahead. While standard time there is `+00:00` (on UTC/GMT), DST moves them one hour ahead of that.

Yet another twist… Even if you say "just pick one", which one? For `+00:00` in just standard time, there are at least 2 three-letter codes (`CET` and `MET`) and 37 named time zones crossing two continents.

Perhaps you are thinking, "I can use the date to figure out if DST was in effect". Nope, DST starts and ends on different dates in various time zones sharing the same offset. Furthermore, some countries (time zones) are sensible enough to not fool with DST.

So regarding your question being "not a simple problem … but that's okay" is wrong. It's not a problem, it's impossible. Like the question, "Given a birthday, determine an individual person". You can determine that a person or time zone is *not* correct, but you cannot determine which *is* correct.

## Record Time Zone With Time

If knowing the time zone (its locality and rules) is important to you, you must record the zone information along with the date-time. This may mean an extra field in your database for example.

[Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings a new [java.time.8 package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). The designers have come to realize the importance of the time zone as a part of a date-time value. As a result, their designs include:

- The main date-time class starts with the word "Zoned" to stress that the class includes time zone info: [ZonedDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)
- Their `toString` implementation on the ZonedDateTime class extends the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by appending the name of the time zone in brackets. Instead of:
  `2014-02-14T20:51:55.427-08:00`
  it outputs
  `2014-02-14T20:51:55.427-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]`

Answer (score 0):

Use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(), and select one (maybe the first) that has only three letters.  You'll have to adjust the offset to numeric milliseconds to pass into that function.  Use of the three letter IDs is deprecated, but it sounds like you are okay with that.